# Possible MoBo compatibility issues

Tags: compatibility, smps

Alright, I purchased [this](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/ibuypower-desktop-amd-fx-series-8gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-black/5574049.p?id=1219143550897&skuId=5574049) PC a few months ago and I am now looking to upgrade the graphics card to the ASUS STRIX GTX 970 and my power supply to the [Corsair CX500M](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139050) because of its good reviews, and I like the idea of having a modular power supply. I cleared out space in my case for these new components, only now I am left wondering if they are truly compatible. I know for a fact that I need ~400 Watts for this to work so I went with a 500 Watt Power supply. The problem is, this PC has a Mother Board that is not too popular.

Mother Board: MSI ms-7641

Will the power supply come with the correct cables for everything to work properly? I am sorry, this may seem like a stupid question to most of you, but as you can probably tell, seeing that I bought a PRE-BUILT PC, that I am new to this. Please, any insight will help my understanding. Thank you for your time.

Here is a link to the [Asus GPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121899&cm_re=gtx_970_strix-_-14-121-899-_-Product), and the [Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130657).

Comment: You really do *not* want to put such a cheap PSU at such high load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first focus on compatability.
On the Newegg Page for the MOBO:

> 1 x ATX 24-pin power connector
>
> 1 x ATX 4-pin 12V CPU power connector

These are standard ATX PSU Connectors that can be found on every ATX-Compatible Power Supply. However, the power supply that you chose is considered not that good in the PC Building Community. At that same price-point ($45), I would recommend the [SeaSonic M12II 520](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151093) as it is made by a manufacturer with a good reputation and even though it is more expensive, it will be able to put out a full 500W which the Corsair unit would not be able to.

Comment: hm... I will reasearch it. But one question, why is the power supply I have chosen so far not looked at as good? What is the issue with it? (other than not being able to put out 500W)

Comment: The manufacture for the CX-Series PSUs use cheaper capacitors, which results in more ripple in the voltages and less heat tolerance, which means the PSU will die faster. You can find much more information with a google search.

Comment: Alright so corsair isn't bad, it is just the CX series that is not great... Thank you!

Comment: I have the 620w version of that PSU. Its awesome. Also has more ports and definately has the right power adaptors for that card.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the PSU ports (FX Series is a bit old), I have used that PSU in console-killer builds for friends. It works amazingly